# it no handler for given file type `flac'

Tags: macos, audio, flac

I hope someone can help me out with this issue.
I have installed the latest version of SoX (14.4.2) on my Mac and I keep getting the following error message:

```
no handler for given file type `flac'
```

I have tried to re-install it, as suggested in another thread on this forum, by running the following:

```
brew remove sox
brew install sox --with-flac
```

but unfortunately did not the trick for me.

By typing :

```
brew info sox
```

I can see the "tick" against the flac option but then when I run the command:

```
sox oldfile.flac newfile.flac trim 0 30
```

I keep getting the same error message.

Any help/suggestion is very much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: I just downloaded [SoX - Sound exchange from SourceForge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/files/sox/), unzipped the download file and `cd sox-14.4.2` and then `./play <pathname_to.flac>` and it played the .flac file just fine.  So not sure why you're using Homebrew to install SoX to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me. Would you please check if the trim command works fine with you? i.e. sox oldfile.flac newfile.flac trim 0 30 Thanks!

Comment: It worked just fine! :)

Comment: Cool! many thanks for letting me know. Much appreciated. I will try  to download the zip file tonight and will report back! Thanks again for your kind help!!

Comment: @ user3439894: Sorry I forgot to ask you if I have to install any specific flac libraries for SoX. thanks!

Comment: I didn't have to install anything after downloading SoX from the URL in my first comment however I do have Audacity and VLC installed.  So I'm not sure if that makes any difference, therefore I'll test it on a stock OS X build to see if it makes any difference and report back in a bit.

Comment: @ user3439894: That's very kind of you. I am using Audacity as well and I can edit flac files with it.

Comment: Okay, just tested it on a clean build of OS X 10.10 with nothing else installed except SoX and it works as expected, it played and trimmed a .flac file just fine.  So maybe it was an issue with getting it via Homebrew.

Comment: @ user3439894: many thanks again for your time. I will try it tonight and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not have a specific answer for the error as I do not use Homebrew however as a *workaround* I've downloaded [SoX - Sound exchange from SourceForge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/files/sox/) unzipped the download file and `cd sox-14.4.2` and then `./play <pathname_to.flac>` and it played the *.flac* file just fine.

As requested in the comments I tested trimming a *.flac* file and this too worked as expected and the trimmed file played fine, (sans the trimmed 30 seconds of course).

To ensure the downloaded SoX worked independently of other installed audio software I tested it on a clean build of OS X 10.10 and SoX worked as expected.  (BTW I originally tested under OS X 10.8.5)

Since Homebrew does the installing and just downloading directly from SourceForge.net does not, I copied the `play, rec, soxi` (aliases) and the `sox` binary to `/usr/local/bin` as it's an appropriate location for third-party binaries and makes the commands directly available in a Terminal as its location is in the `$PATH`.

Comment: Good news! I followed your instructions and that worked like a charm! Many thanks for helping me out with this! Very much appreciated! Unfortunately I can't vote up for you as I need 15 reputations but I managed to click on the 'tick' which is now green :)

Comment: Hey I'm glad it worked out for you and I have a new utility to use too, so thanks for asking the question and I up voted your question since I learned about a new utility that I have a use for.  BTW I've found that because I have Xcode and CLU installed I can bypass using Homebrew and install from source code the programs I want that don't already have a MacOS binary readily available to install otherwise.  Of course in this case there was already a MacOS binary of SoX to easily install without either. :)